# vphython stops to work for me in jupyter notebooks every few minutes for no reason

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vpython, glowscript

I am having massive trouble with using vpython in jupyter notbooks. I'm creating small animations with vpython. After a couple of minutes when I try to run a cell, it will either not show any output or will yield a error message "object could not be called". 
The only fix I found for this is to restart or change the kernel. Most times it works then for the next few minutes until it stops again. This is really annoying and prevents real progress.

[pictrue of error message with example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtP6u.png)
all used objects have been imported in another cell before this one.

I am running vpython 7.3.2 and anaconda navigator 1.6.10 on a mac with High Sierra. As a browser I use Chrome.

Thank u for every hint to fix this permanently in advance!

Cheers,

Gordon

Comment: You will increase the change to get a good answer if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Pleas add your source as text, including all relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

Try asking your question on the vpython forum and perhaps provide a sample notebook on github where with instructions on how to reproduce the problem.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&hl=en#!forum/vpython-users

Here is a link to demo vpython notebooks running in the cloud using binder service.

https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/BruceSherwood/vpython-jupyter/master?filepath=Demos

If you provide a notebook on github that demonstrates the problem then it should be reproduceable when running on mybinder.

https://mybinder.org/